# In which points is this map a local diffeomorphism?

Tags: complex-analysis, diffeomorphism

Let $f: \mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$ be the map $(z,w)\mapsto(z^3-w^3,zw)$. In which points $(z,w)$ is f a local diffeomorphism?

I struggle to solve this problem. From what I know a diffeomorphism is a bijective map whose inverse is differentiable (?) Now what makes a local diffeomorphism and how could I use that to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the inverse mapping theorem?

Comment: Well, I just constructed the Jacobian matrix and saw that the derivative is nonzero as long as $(z,w) \neq (0,0)$. That seems to be a requirement for the inverse function theorem. Now is this the right way and if so how would I continue?

Comment: My suggestion is to read the precise statement of the Inverse Mapping Theorem. Then you will be able to solve the problem.